# Clustering a set of images

Tags: python, opencv, dbscan

I have a folder with hundres/thousands of images, some of them look alike. I would like to create clusters separating those images (those which look alike in the same cluster).

I can't determine the number of clusters that will be needed, it depends on the images.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do this using Python, OpenCV and which algorithm to use?

I've made some research and found that AffinityPropagation or DBSCAN can be useful for me but I don't know where to start (how to encode my images, what should I pass to those algorithms etc...)

Comment: One simple solution worth trying is PCA / Eigenfaces. Eigenfaces is a method designed to compress profile images but also defines a similarity metric based on which you can define your clusters. I am not sure that it would work but there are a bunch of tutorials in the topic and is also available out of the box in newer OpenCV versions so it worth a shot.

Comment: Also, any way you use, you almost certainly have to come up with a way to project your initial data to the same spatial dimensions. Easiest solution: downsample everything to the minimum image size.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not that simple with images, since naively clustering would result in clusters of images with the same colors, not the same "content". You can use a neural network as a feature extractor for the images, I see two options:

1. Use a pre-trained network and get the features from an intermediate layer
2. Train an autoencoder on your dataset, and use the latent features

Option 1 is cheaper since you can easily find pre-trained models, option 2 is much more computationally expensive but should work better, especially if there is no pre-trained model on your domain.

[This tutorial](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-unsupervised-clustering-with-keras/) (randomly found on the internet) seems to be a good introduction to method 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually it could be useful for me to detect if two images have the same colors. I didn't explain well but let's say I have a video and I extract an image each second. I will surely have images with the same person/object for a few seconds and I would like to identify those images

Comment: @MounaBenChamekh you could definitely try clustering directly on the pixels! Another idea, if you know the images are in a sequence (e.g. in a video): you can compute the distance between adjacent images, and say the images are in the same cluster if they're closer than x. Unfortunately, regardless of the method you choose, you will need to perform quite some experiments to get the parameters right

Comment: Would clustering directly on the pixels work? Because even though the images look alike, objects change position, the colors are not exactly the same... How to take all of that into consideration?

Comment: @MounaBenChamekh the idea is that adjacent frames in a video should be quite similar. But no, I don't thing clustering on the pixels would work very well, honestly

Comment: Autoencoders compress information but you can't really define similarity by them. If you go with neural networks then what you need is an embedding scheme (which projects close in Euclidean space when things are similar in regard of some metric).